# Close Notification box automatically in Oracle Apex form

Tags: oracle-apex

[notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahqsK.png)Hi,,,
On successful creation of a record in ORacle APEX form, a green coloured notification appears. Is there anyway to close that notification automatically after 10-20 seconds? sample pic below.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Global page(page 0)

Set a dynamic action, on page load

Set it to execute Javascript:

```
apex.message.setThemeHooks({
  beforeShow: function(pMsgType, pElement$){
    if (pMsgType=='success'){ 
   setTimeout(function() {
        $('.t-Alert').fadeOut('slow');
      }, 5000);
    }   
  }
});
```

I have it set to 5 sec, the 5000 in the code, but you can have it whatever you want.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for response.  For some reason, it didn't work for me.. Clicking button to create record is not triggering due to this. Is there any other alternative please?

Comment: That is extremely odd.
Are you sure its to do with this and not some other change?
Have you tried disabling the dynamic action and seeing if it for sure worked?

Comment: Also, what version of APEX are you using?

Comment: Hi.. Version - 5.0.4.00.12 Yes, it's definitely due to this change. After creating the global page and the dynamic action some of the required actions are not triggered. I disabled the dynamic action and worked normally.

Comment: I have never dealt with 5.0, but a quick google implies those should go away by themselves. Also found this that you could try: http://thalbachdevelop.blogspot.com/2017/01/oracle-apex-51-fade-success-message.html